# How do I get something from the comments of a webpage with Capybara?

Tags: ruby, capybara

Following another question, I tried to use titles for unique identifiers, but eventually discovered that they are non-unique on the site I'm working with. However, each page includes a unique identifier in a comment.

Using Capybara, how can I access the comments on a web page? Specifically, a comment at the root, BEFORE the first html. Inside that, I can at least use capybara to grab the element containing the comment (even if I cannot grab the comment), but I don't seem to be able to do it from the root at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not an optimal solution, but at the very least this can be accomplished with by parsing the "body" of your current session directly with a regex or something.

```
page.source.scan(/<!--.*?-->/m)
```

will give you an array containing all the comments on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Having to address exactly the same issue you describe, I implemented the following custom RSpec Matcher

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :have_comment do |comment|
    match do |page|
      page.has_xpath?(".//comment()[.=' #{comment} ']")
    end
end
```

It can be used as follows:

```
page.should have_comment("the comment text you are looking for")
```

The above implementation matches the whole comment body, including a space before and a space after it, but it should be relatively easy to modify it to look for arbitrary RegEx.